# Clear app from running app list

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I want to check when user leave app,click home button or etc .I searched and found one small and very helpful function.This function working perfect

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint()
{
  super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

Now i want to clear(kill servece) app from running app list,when user click home button.Is it a possible? how i can solve my problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

to the launcher activity in your manifest file, and this will hide the app from the recents list when home button is pressed.

Comment: I'm using Nexus 5 emulator and it's not working.I added it in my manifest file @Sup